# Why Visual Studio 2013 automatically excludes new files from the TFS

Tags: visual-studio-2013, tfs, team-explorer

Just moved from Visual Studio 2010 to Visual Studio 2013 and I'm trying to get used to the idea of excluded files in the Team Explorer.

I read that in order to prevent Visual Studio from auto excluding files I need to add .tfignore file.

I did that and also added a section to only ignore the packages and bin directories and that didn't help.

Every time I add a new file, Visual Studio automatically excludes it, causing me to check-in only some of the files (until I realize I have some files "stuck" in the excluded section).

Can you please assist?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I had to bind my projects and that solved it.

Go to File-->Source Control-->Advanced-->Change Source Control

Select each solution\project and click on bind.

That should solve the issue.